# Can multiple dynamically created quill editors use the same toolbar

Tags: javascript, quill

I try to realise a light web version of Indesign as a student project. I dynamically create a div thats supposed to be a textfield. I want dynamically create a quill editor inside each textfield. They should all be linked to the same toolbar but it seems that quill isn`t able to to any of these things for me.

Does someone know if it is possible to implement with Quill if yes how?
If not, does someone know an alternative for me?

I already tried to link all to the same toolbar, some features throw errors, some work but when they to they work on all editors together or other strange behavior happens.

```
HTML:

<div id="toolbar-container">
    <span class="ql-formats">
        <select class="ql-size"></select>
    </span></div>
<div id="editor-container1"></div>
<div id="editor-container2"></div>  

JS:

var options = {
    modules: {
        toolbar: '#toolbar-container'
    },
    theme: 'snow'
};
new Quill('#editor-container1', options);
new Quill('#editor-container2', options);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can bind the same toolbar on the multiple quill-editor instances but I have a solution.

What you can do instead is using multiple 'display' views (if you've used ngx-quill for exemple it's the difference with a `quill-view` and a `quill-editor`).

Theses views are not editable but can display quill formatted content.When you click on one of them you can get the content, bind it to an instance of quill editor, place the editor at the same place / width as your 'view' zone and show it.
Like this you can "fake" multiple instances of the editor with a "shared" toolbar. It will be the same toolbar and editor hidden and displayed over non editable zones.

EDIT : 
Here is a working exemple https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-quill-editor?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: There you go https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t8utuu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html 
You can see multiple instance of a viewer component with one editor component.
I kept the toolbar very simple for this exemple but you can make your own.
Hope it helped poke @Enni

Comment: I updated the link as I renamed the Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-quill-editor?file=src/app/app.component.ts